# Constructor Parameter Using This Difference?

Tags: java, variables, parameters

I have two classes. Both of them refer to the same variables inside the constructor. I am confused, when I used `this.name` I don't need to change the name of the parameter, the Java compiler knows that I am referring to the main variable?

On the second class example, the parameters name was changed but it is not using `this`. 
What is the different between these two classes? 
Are they both considred "good programming" ?

```
class Account {
     private string name;
     private int amount;

     Account(String name, int amount) {
      this.name = name;
      this.amount = amount;
     }
    }
```

---

```
class Account {
 private string name;
 private int amount;

 Account(String n, int a) {
  name = n;
  amount = a;
 }   
}
```

Comment: `this` in the 2nd case is added implicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java allows to use same name for instance variable and local variable/parameter.

When method/constructor parameter name is same as instance variable name then we need to explicitly use `this` keyword to inform JVM that we are trying to use this instance variable; not local variable. Otherwise, for same named variables without `this` JVM selects more specific scope variable.

For first case you are using same variable name for parameter and instance variable called `name` so you need to explicitly define which one is your instance variable using `this` as bellow:

```
this.name = name;
```

For second case, there is no naming confusion so if you don't use `this` there is no problem to identify instance variable.

**N.B.**
It is better to use `this` for readability when you are accessing instance variables.

Answer (score 2):

In this case `Account(String name, int amount)` if your code says `name = "ABC";`, it is setting the parameter `name`, not the member. If you want to set the member, you need you reference it via `this.name`.

So `name = name;` does nothing (sets the parameter to itself). `this.name = name;` sets the member to the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Both of your codes are not wrong.! But,  In Java it's considered poor practice to use meaningless name prefixes or suffixes to distinguish instance variables from parameters from local variables. I would like to recommend to use whatever names make the code easiest to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Either are fine. You would only use this.name if you wanted the private instance variable to also be called name. When you have an instance variable that is a different name than the parameter taken in, it does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the different between this two classes?

Functionally none. Compiler will change your 2nd example as follows:

```
Account(String n, int a)
{
    this.name = n;
    this.amount = a;
}
```

> Are both ways consider "good programming"?

I prefer 1st way to write code.